# How to use Moq framework to test Objectfactory.GetNamedInstance of structure map

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, structuremap

I am actually using constructor injection for initializing all other classes using Dependency injection and registering them using scan. I was not able to find a replacement for ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance(string parameter);

But to initialize using like this in constructor have to do same for all other classe. So, I initialized it where ever I need within class

. And everthing worked good. But have no idea how to use Moq framework unit testing to test this class. Its failing whenever it hits named Instance.

```
  IDmsDataRulesManager dmsDataRulesManager =
                ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IDmsDataRulesManager>(dmsManifest.DmsManifestMetaData.TargetTable);
```

please help me with replacement for GetNamedInstance or how to test it

Comment: [check here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: unit testing static methods are very difficult. create an abstraction that wraps that functionality and then you should be able to mock that.

Comment: Thanks for help, I figure it out using                              `ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.AddRegistry<Registry>();
            });` in unit test which missed it before